# Why spock mocking void method does not work

Tags: spock

In specification I want to mock class:

`com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser`

I try to do this like this:

```
        parser = Stub() 
        parser.stopParsing() >> null
```

or

```
        parser.stopParsing() >>  {}
```

Nothing works.

Always original class method is called.

I tried it with 2 and 3 version of Groovy and correct Spock version.

a) what I need to do, to make this work?

b) where I can find in documentation info about
why original class method is called for Stub or Mock?

Comment: can you show the complete test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spock cannot mock `final` classes and/or methods and [CsvParser](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/csv/CsvParser.java) as well as [stopParsing()](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/943a542c909709b5e4e7ccd97831bc2d6b8673f4/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/common/AbstractParser.java#L436) are final. You can try using the [spock mockable](https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable) extension to make those classes/methods non-`final`.